# Loading delay when using react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, svg, react-navigation, react-native-svg

I am using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg) for handling SVG but i am noticing a ****delay** when switching** to a stack/screen that contains SVG. I am using a **tabBar** in **react-navigation 6** to switch stacks/screens.

When i have SVG in the screen as below i can notice a small delay of around 0,5-1s before the stack/screen shows up. If i remove all SVG it switches just fine with 0s delay.

I have tried with [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer) but the delay just increases.

I have around **10 SVG:s** as below in one screen.

```
import { WithLocalSvg } from 'react-native-svg';

<WithLocalSvg width="28" height="28" style={{position:'absolute', top:16, left:0, transform: [{ rotate: '12deg' }]}} asset={require("../../images/svg_source.svg")} />
```

Any tips or ideas are welcome. Maybe there is another way to work with SVG in react-native?

Comment: this is exactly my problem. have you found the workaround?

Comment: I reverted back to using png as i never found a solution.

Comment: I resorted to using a WebView, https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md.  I'm sure it'll cause other problems (I'm an RN noob), but my SVG string has gone from long enough to get a cup of tea (then crashing) to more-or-less instant...

Answer (score 1):

> Another approach is to use a library called react-native-fast-image,
> which is a performant image-loading library for react-native. It loads
> images as quickly as possible, and also supports SVG files.
>
> and the delay you're experiencing when switching to a screen
> containing SVG is likely due to the fact that the SVG images are being
> loaded asynchronously, which can cause a delay in the rendering of the
> screen.

Comment: All the svg images are stored locally so i guess react-native-fast-image wont help? But i will try :)

Comment: It seems not to work with local stored svg :(